# How can I bypass a clearcase "file already exists" error?

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

I try to add a file in a branch to source control by doing this:

`ct mkelem -ci -nc`

and I get this error:

```
File already exists in "other_branch" branch.

Resolution: Since this file already exisit in ClearCase you will have to, selectively, merge this file from other_branch branch to your current branch/view.
```

Well, `other_branch` is completely obsolete and I would like to use the current branch file im trying to merge 100% as is. Is there a way to communicate this to clearcase on the commandline? Like ct mkelem -force (or -replaceAnyOtherFileWithThisName) -ci -nc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not many solutions, beside removing completely that element (which can be dangerous in general, except in your case, this is about an obsolete branch).

```
cleartool rmelem
```

But a "safer" route would be to try an *merge* that obsolete branch, ignoring all changes except the addition of that file.
That way, you don't have to '`mkelem`' the same file again, you can reuse the one existing (and changing its content completely).

Comment: Yes this looks exactly like what I want. Much to my chagrin though It's giving me a "No permission to perform operation "remove element"." error saying I have to be element owner, VOB owner, or root...confused because this is my branch and i created this file back in the day in that old branch and ct mkelem-ed it!

Comment: @PalaceChan it is best, then, to forward the request to your ClearCase admin, who can force the delete.

Comment: Thanks, will have to do that.